# SQL exclusive or on insert

Tags: mysql

if've got three tables in my MYSQL Database and want to connect two of this table with one table. The tables look like this

```
CONNECTTABLE
+----+-----------+---------+
| ID | search_id | room_id |
+----+-----------+---------+

SEARCHTABLE
+----+-----------+-----+
| ID | search_id | ... |
+----+-----------+-----+

SEARCHTABLE
+----+---------+-----+
| ID | room_id | ... |
+----+---------+-----+
```

Is it possible to ensure via MYSQL that in the CONNECTTABLE only search_id OR room_id is not null per datarow? If I can do so, how can I do so?

```
Valid rows:
+----+-----------+---------+
| ID | search_id | room_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 |    42     |   NULL  |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  2 |   NULL    |   1337  |
+----+-----------+---------+

Invalid row:
+----+-----------+---------+
| ID | search_id | room_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  3 |    42     |   17    |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

Best regards,
Gerrit

Comment: What you're asking makes no sense to me. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Feysal the OP maybe wants to check if the `ID` in `CONNECTTABLE` does not exist in either of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a "CHECK constraint". Unfortunately, MySQL does not support them. Well, it will let you define them, but it won't actually check them. [This article](http://web.archive.org/web/20060222000819/http://mysql.gilfster.com/page.php?parent_id=2&page_id=2.0.7) discusses using triggers to implement the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I've coded a trigger: http://snipt.net/esco/entweder-spalte-a-oder-spalte-b/ which works for me. The SELECT statement was not the problem, I want to be sure that the INSERTed data are valid.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear, you are saying that CHECKs are absolutely useless in mySQL?

Comment: Correct. "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines." from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
select * from tableName where search_id is null && room_id is not null 
union
select * from tableName where search_id is not null && room_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not possible to add two tables with the same name in the database. But i presume that this are only dummy tablenames right? try this one:

```
SELECT  a.ID, b.Search_ID, c.Room_ID
  FROM  ConnectTable a LEFT JOIN SearchTableA b 
               ON a.ID = b.ID
           LEFT JOIN SearchTableB c
               ON a.ID = c.ID
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL OR
        c.ID IS NULL
```